# OpenVPN can't update to ver 2.4.0 on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I'm stuck on OpenVPN version 2.3.11 in Ubuntu 16.10, which looks like it's 10 months old. Want to update to the latest stable version 2.4.0

Tried to update using [these instructions](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/OpenvpnSoftwareRepos) so did these commands from the above link: `sudo -s`, the `wget` command, `echo "deb build..."` - version replaced with stable, and osrelease replaced with yakkety. (also tried version replaced with 2.4)

When I do `apt update` I get the error:

```
E: The repository 'build.openvpn.net/debian/openvpn/stable yakkety Release' does not have a Release file.
```

Comment: Notice that the page you linked only shows repos for xenial and older.  It does not list one for yakkety.

Comment: You need to ask the maintainer of that repository / ppa to add packages for newer versions of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

When I installed OpenVPN on my Ubuntu 16.04 using `sudo apt-get install openvpn`, it installed version 2.3.10.

I ran the following commands to get version 2.4.9 installed:

```
curl -s https://swupdate.openvpn.net/repos/repo-public.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb http://build.openvpn.net/debian/openvpn/stable xenial main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvpn-aptrepo.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y openvpn
```